# Making 150,000 SQL queries faster?

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc

I have a table with approximately 1.1 million rows and 12 columms.  Those columns are a name of an element (set as clustered non-unique index), a date and 10 integers containing statistics.  The data is about a week's worth of statistics for a bit over 150,000 elements.

The database is on ms-sql-server 2008 and is external to my PC.

I am to generate a report which shows all statistics for all 150,000+ elements for the past week.  I query the DB one element at a time, so that would be about 150,000+ queries in total with each ResultSet returning 7 rows.  It takes about a second to complete 5 queries.  This is too slow for a daily report.

So, is this just life or is there something I can do to speed this up?  While working on this I had removed all processing of the ResultSet to ensure that most of the time is actually spent executing the query.

JDBC

```
Statement stmt = m_connection.createStatement(); 
ResultSet rs   = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DB_TABLE_PVG_STATISTICS + " WHERE " + Data.PVG_SPAN_NAME +  "='" + pvgSpanName + "' ORDER BY " + Data.DATE + " DESC");
```

An attempt to better explain the data in the table.  Below is an abbreviated mock up of the data.

```
Detroit laps/400 sts/0 vt1dot5/1,1 | 06-02-14 | 13400916 | 13408882 | 45 | 32 | 6  ...
Detroit laps/400 sts/0 vt1dot5/1,1 | 06-01-14 | 12000825 | 19998206 | 43 | 21 | 5  ...
Detroit laps/400 sts/0 vt1dot5/1,2 | 06-02-14 | 13001056 | 13001007 | 67 | 2  | 78 ...
Detroit laps/400 sts/0 vt1dot5/1,2 | 06-01-14 | 11001078 | 11000002 | 42 | 2  | 45 ...
Omaha laps/400 sts/0 vt1dot5/1,1   | 06-02-14 | 13001056 | 13001007 | 67 | 2  | 78 ...
Omaha laps/400 sts/0 vt1dot5/1,2   | 06-01-14 | 11001078 | 11000002 | 42 | 2  | 45 ...
etc...
```

"Detroit laps/400 sts/0 vt1dot5/1,1" is an example of a pvgSpanName.  "Detroit laps/400 sts/0 vt1dot5/1,2" is another one.  There are 150,000+ more unique pvgSpanNames in the table.

Each pvgSpanName will have 7 days of data.  Above, only two days are shown in the example per pvgSpanName.  Along with the pvgSpanName column and the date column are 10 more columns of statistics.  Only 5 are shown in the example.

150,000+ pvgSpanNames * 7 days = 1,000,000+ rows.

The ResultSet for each query (one per pvgSpanName) is 7 rows (1 row per date).  The ResultSet is parsed by the java program and eventually gets stored to a .txt file for upload to a webpage.  The output looks similar to the following

```
Detroit laps/400 sts/0 vt1dot5/1,1

               Running  ErrorFree  Errored  Frame   CRC      More
     Date         Time    Seconds  Seconds  Errors  Errors   Stats
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
06-02-14 Mon  13400916  13408882     45       32      6      ...
06-01-14 Sun  12000825  19998206     43       21      5      ...
05-31-14 Sat  13400916  13408882     43       21      5      ...
05-30-14 Fri  13400916  13408882     42       21      4      ...
05-29-14 Thu  13400916  13408882     42       21      4      ...
05-28-14 Wed  13400916  13408882     41       21      3      ...
05-27-14 Tue  13400916  13408882     41       21      3      ...
-----------------------------------------------------------------------



Detroit laps/400 sts/0 vt1dot5/1,2

               Running  ErrorFree  Errored  Frame   CRC      More
     Date         Time    Seconds  Seconds  Errors  Errors   Stats
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
06-02-14 Mon  13001056  13001007     67        2      78     ...
06-01-14 Sun  11001078  11000002     42        2      45     ...
05-31-14 Sat  13400916  13408882     42        2       5     ...
05-30-14 Fri  13400916  13408882     42        2       4     ...
05-29-14 Thu  13400916  13408882     42        2       4     ...
05-28-14 Wed  13400916  13408882     42        2       3     ...
05-27-14 Tue  13400916  13408882     42        2       3     ...
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

and so on for each pvgSpanName.
```

FYI: I don't have access to the actual data at this moment so don't pay much attention to the actual values for the statistics.

Comment: Retrieving one row at a time is definitely not the right approach.  However, you don't give enough information to say what the best approach really is.  Can you provide sample data and what you want your report to look like?  You might be able to do all the data processing in SQL.

Comment: I'm curious to hear about the answer. I heard once that naming your column is better in term of performance. And I agree with @GordonLinoff

Comment: Perhaps my brain has just left for the day, but I don't get at all what you've got going on.  150k queries against the table with 1.1 million rows and 12 columns?

Comment: you should let the SQL do the work... take advantage of GROUP BY and other aggregations to perform the report with one query not 150,000

Comment: Naming columns is absolutely more efficient, especially if you're not using all of the results.  Even swapping the where condition to state where in (list of pvgSpanNames here) would be more efficient than running the same query 150k times

Comment: Thanks for the comments thus far.  I'll investigate them when I wake up.  I've added some additional information regarding the data I'm working with and where I'm headed with it.

Comment: Can you explain why you think you need to do 150k instead of making a query that will return all the information in a single shot ? It seems to me that in your case, optimization is not the solution. You have to rethink what you are doing... or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Alexandre,  150k queries was just naturally where I started.  Since the output report is based on the pvgSpanNames and their stats for the recent week it seemed normal just to make a query for each pvgSpanName when I was ready for it.  I could create a query which returns all 1 million rows and write some code which parses the ResultSet directly rather than passing it to an PvgSpan object that takes care of that.  Hmmm.  Anyways, the Ambien is really having an effect so I;m not sure how much any of what I typed made sense.  Might b interesting t see the memory ramifications of a 1M ResultSet.

Comment: Is there no way to make a query that will yield the 150k records times the rows for each report ?

Comment: What I've done is wrote a query to retrieve all 1 million rows while sorting them by pvgSpanName and date.  That takes about 5 seconds.  The java program then parses the ResultSet and generates the reports in about 15 minutes.  Much better than the projected 9 hours.  Memory impact was minimal.  I use every column of every row so I don't think GROUP BY or other aggregators will help me here.  However, I pretty much use DB as a just a super csv so I know there's plenty of capabilities I have no clue exist.